# Creating a wireless communication between two hosts using UdpBasicApp

Tags: omnet++

I have created two apps one UdpBasicApp and another UdpSink. My purpose is to send from sender to receiver and then add a pcap recording to see the packet content. I am getting this error:

```
Module not found on path 'interfaceTable' defined by par 'MyNetwork.receiver.interfaceTableModule' -- in module (inet::UdpSink) MyNetwork.receiver (id=3), at t=0s, event #1
```

I have created MySenderApp module that extends a UdpBasicApp

```
import inet.applications.udpapp.UdpBasicApp;

module MySenderApp extends UdpBasicApp {
  
}
```

This is the header of MySenderApp moduke

```
#ifndef MYSENDERAPP_H_
#define MYSENDERAPP_H_



#include <omnetpp.h>
using namespace omnetpp;
class MySenderApp : public cSimpleModule {
public:
    MySenderApp();
    virtual ~MySenderApp();

protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage* msg) override;
};

#endif /* MYSENDERAPP_H_ */
```

And this is the c++ code that I have used to send packets to the receiver:

```
#include "MySenderApp.h"
#include <omnetpp.h>
using namespace omnetpp;


Define_Module(MySenderApp);

MySenderApp::MySenderApp() {
    // Constructor
}

MySenderApp::~MySenderApp() {
    // Destructor
}

void MySenderApp::initialize() {
    // Initialization code, if needed
    // Example: schedule a self-message to send a UDP packet
    //server =getModuleByPath("MyReceiverApp");
    cMessage* msg = new cMessage("SendUDP");
    scheduleAt(simTime() + 1.0, msg);
}

void MySenderApp::handleMessage(cMessage* msg) {
    if (msg->isSelfMessage()) {
        // Create and send a UDP packet
        cPacket* packet = new cPacket("MyPacket");

        send(packet,"socketOut");
        delete msg;  // Delete the self-message
    }
}
```

Similarly, I have created a module MyReceiverApp.ned that extends UdpSink

```
import inet.applications.udpapp.UdpSink;
import inet.networklayer.common.InterfaceTable;

module MyReceiverApp extends UdpSink {
    parameters:
        interfaceTableModule = "^";
   
}
```

And this is the c++ code:

```
#include "MyReceiverApp.h"
#include <omnetpp.h>


using namespace omnetpp;


Define_Module(MyReceiverApp);

MyReceiverApp::MyReceiverApp() {
    // Constructor
}

MyReceiverApp::~MyReceiverApp() {
    // Destructor
}

void MyReceiverApp::initialize() {
    // Initialization code, if needed
}

void MyReceiverApp::handleMessage(cMessage* msg) {
    // Handle incoming UDP packets here
    EV << "Received UDP packet: " << msg->getName() << endl;
    delete msg;
}
```

My network ned file is as shown below:

```
network MyNetwork
{
    @display("bgb=341,381");
    submodules:
        sender: MySenderApp {
            @display("p=85,76");
            @networkNode;
        }

        
        receiver: MyReceiverApp {
            @display("p=290,178");
            @networkNode;
        }

    connections allowunconnected:
        sender.socketOut --> receiver.socketIn;
        receiver.socketOut --> sender.socketIn;

       
}
```

And my omnetpp.ini file is:

```
[General]
network = MyNetwork
debug-on-errors = true

sim-time-limit = 5s
record-eventlog = true
```

I think the error deals with the interface table, but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77091303/edit) the question and provide your full NED file as well as `omnetpp.ini`?

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question.
I have just edited the question>
One more thing, could you please give me an idea on how to make this connection wireless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UDPApp` cannot be used as a host. You must use `StandardHost` or `WirelessHost` and add your UDP application to instances of these hosts.
Take a look at Wireless Tutorial, especially at `inet/tutorials/wireless/WirelessA.ned` and section `[Config Wireless01]` in `inet/tutorials/wireless/omnetpp.ini`.

In short you should:

1. Create simple module (called for example `MyUDPApp`) for your UDP application (look at examples in `inet/src/inet/applications/udpapp`).
2. Create your network using `WirelessHost`.
3. Add your application for hosts you want by writing in `omnetpp.ini` at least:

   ```
   **.host1.numUdpApps = 1
   **.host1.udpApp[0].typename = "MyUDPApp"
   # other parameters of the application
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Would it still consider the c++ files?

Comment: Yes. You have to prepare C++ files that describe the behavior of your application.